String data not allowed in RDF document and stripping error
I have an RDF document below. Using the RDF validator, I cannot understand what the errors are about. Can anyone help?
Why is the string data not allowed? What is the stripping error?
Thank you.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:vCard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#"
    xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/#"
    xmlns:dcat="http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#"
    xmlns:pav="http://purl.org/pav#"
    xmlns:prov="http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#"
    xmlns:spdx="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:bqmodel="http://biomodels.net/model-qualifiers/#"
    xmlns:bqbiol="http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/#"
    xmlns:bmTerms="https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/terms#"
    xml:base="http://localhost:8080/biomodels/MODEL2409040001">

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/biomodels/MODEL2409040001">
        <bmTerms:Overview rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/biomodels/MODEL2409040001#Overview"/>
        <bmTerms:Files rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/biomodels/MODEL2409040001#Files"/>
        <bmTerms:History rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/biomodels/MODEL2409040001#History"/>
        <bmTerms:Contributors rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/biomodels/MODEL2409040001#Contributors"/>
    </rdf:Description>
    
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Files">
        <spdx:hasFile rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <spdx:fileName>BIOMD0000000500_url.xml</spdx:fileName>
            <spdx:description>SBML L2V4 representation of Begitt2014 - STAT1 cooperative DNA binding - single GAS polymer model</spdx:description>
            <dcat:byteSize>50580</dcat:byteSize>
            <dcat:mediaType>application/xml</dcat:mediaType>
            <bmTerms:mainFile>False</bmTerms:mainFile>
            <spdx:checksum xml:base="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#">
                <spdx:checksumAlgorithm rdf:resource="checksumAlgorithm_md5" />
                <spdx:checksumValue>ba63683fb5b342177401d514c89b5963</spdx:checksumValue>
            </spdx:checksum>
            <spdx:checksum xml:base="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#">
                <spdx:checksumAlgorithm rdf:resource="checksumAlgorithm_sha1" />
                <spdx:checksumValue>d6a770ba38583ed4bb4525bd96e50461655d2758</spdx:checksumValue>
            </spdx:checksum>
            <spdx:checksum xml:base="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#">
                <spdx:checksumAlgorithm rdf:resource="checksumAlgorithm_sha256" />
                <spdx:checksumValue>9d2715825a5d164c49b6a06743316b23a674e79c97d8575924cf42a359488c10</spdx:checksumValue>
            </spdx:checksum>
        </spdx:hasFile>

        <spdx:hasFile rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <spdx:fileName>BIOMD0000000500_url.xml</spdx:fileName>
            <spdx:description>SBML L2V4 representation of Begitt2014 - STAT1 cooperative DNA binding - single GAS polymer model</spdx:description>
            <dcat:byteSize>50580</dcat:byteSize>
            <dcat:mediaType>application/xml</dcat:mediaType>
            <bmTerms:mainFile>False</bmTerms:mainFile>
            <spdx:checksum xml:base="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#">
                <spdx:checksumAlgorithm rdf:resource="checksumAlgorithm_md5" />
                <spdx:checksumValue>ba63683fb5b342177401d514c89b5963</spdx:checksumValue>
            </spdx:checksum>
            <spdx:checksum xml:base="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#">
                <spdx:checksumAlgorithm rdf:resource="checksumAlgorithm_sha1" />
                <spdx:checksumValue>d6a770ba38583ed4bb4525bd96e50461655d2758</spdx:checksumValue>
            </spdx:checksum>
            <spdx:checksum xml:base="http://spdx.org/rdf/terms#">
                <spdx:checksumAlgorithm rdf:resource="checksumAlgorithm_sha256" />
                <spdx:checksumValue>9d2715825a5d164c49b6a06743316b23a674e79c97d8575924cf42a359488c10</spdx:checksumValue>
            </spdx:checksum>
        </spdx:hasFile>

    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="#History">
        <pav:hasVersion rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <pav:version>1</pav:version>
            <pav:createdOn>2024-07-31T06:40:57Z</pav:createdOn>
            <dct:modified>2024-07-31T06:40:57Z</dct:modified>
            <pav:createdBy>Teo Nguyen</pav:createdBy>
            <rdfs:comment>Import of Rosas2015 - Caffeine-induced luminal SR calcium changes</rdfs:comment>
        </pav:hasVersion>
        
        <pav:hasCurrentVersion rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <pav:version>2</pav:version>
            <pav:createdOn>2024-08-01T06:40:57Z</pav:createdOn>
            <!-- or use dct:modified -->
            <dct:modified>2024-08-01T06:40:57Z</dct:modified>
            <pav:createdBy>Rahuman Jordan</pav:createdBy>
            <rdfs:comment>Updated the publication details</rdfs:comment>
        </pav:hasCurrentVersion>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Overview">
        <dct:identifier>MODEL2409040001</dct:identifier>
        <dct:title>Rosas2015 - Caffeine-induced luminal SR calcium changes</dct:title>
        <dct:description>For Testing, Get a Simple Description</dct:description>
        <dct:format>SBML L2V4</dct:format>
        <dct:keyword>Machine Learning</dct:keyword>
        <dct:keyword>Diseases</dct:keyword>
        <dcterms:created>2024-10-24T18:53:42.524+01:00</dcterms:created>
        <bmTerms:curationStatus>NON_CURATED</bmTerms:curationStatus>
        <bmTerms:modellingApproach rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/mamo/MAMO_0000046"/>
        <dcterms:creator>The BioModels Team &lt;biomodels-cura@ebi.ac.uk&gt;</dcterms:creator>
        <bqbiol:isVersionOf rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/go/GO:0014808"/>
        <bqmodel:is rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/biomodels.db/MODEL1406180001"/>
        <bqbiol:hasTaxon rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/taxonomy/10141"/>
        <bqbiol:occursIn rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/bto/BTO:0001849"/>
        <bqmodel:isDescribedBy rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/pubmed/26390403"/>
        <bqbiol:hasProperty rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/mamo/MAMO_0000046"/>
        <bqmodel:is rdf:resource="http://identifiers.org/biomodels.db/BIOMD0000000601"/>
        <bqmodel:isDescribedBy rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/pubmed:26390403"/>
        <bqmodel:is rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/biomodels.db:MODEL2409040001"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Contributors">
        <dct:contributor rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <prov:Organization>EBI</prov:Organization>
            <foaf:name>Teo Nguyen</foaf:name>
            <foaf:mbox>hello@aaa.ac.uk</foaf:mbox>
            <bmTerms:isExternalContributor>False</bmTerms:isExternalContributor>
            <dcat:hadRole rdf:about="https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/terms#submitter"/>
            <bmTerms:orcid>0000-0002-9999-2222</bmTerms:orcid>
        </dct:contributor>
        <dct:contributor rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <prov:Organization>University of Washington</prov:Organization>
            <foaf:name>Lorenzo Soleni</foaf:name>
            <foaf:mbox>sss@aaa.edu</foaf:mbox>
            <bmTerms:isExternalContributor>True</bmTerms:isExternalContributor>
            <dcat:hadRole rdf:about="https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/terms#curator"/>
            <bmTerms:orcid>0000-0001-3333-5555</bmTerms:orcid>
        </dct:contributor>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>


did you manually create the RDF/XML document? I'm wondering why you did use rdf:parseType="Collection" in your code if that doesn't map to collection of elements? What you want is to declare an RDF resource, either named or bnode
